# Функции и Лямбда выражения - C++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, sfml, лямбда-выражение

Доброго времени суток, дорогие форумчане!
Всплыл вопрос: "Вот хочу сделать функцию и передавать ей как аргумент какое-то условие допустим i == j, функция обработки двумерного массива, и я не понимаю как мне это реализовать! И возможно ли как-то использовать для этого лямбда выражения?"
Как работают последние я тоже не совсем понимаю. Все примеры что я видел используют уже имеющиеся, Стандартные функции, такие как sort() и другие. Как же сделать функцию которая сможет работать с лямбда выражениями?

Comment: вы хотя бы псевдокодом напишите, что хотите сделать в методе и как он будет работать.

Comment: есть функция:
`var getSumMas(var** M, int N, bool i){
    var S=0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
            if(i)
                S+=M[i][j];
    return S;
}`

вызов функции:

Comment: вызов функции:
getSumMas(A, N, i == j);

Comment: Но вы же и так это сделали :)

Answer (score 4):

Лямбды и иже с ними нужны там, где вы на ходу меняете **поведение**.

Например, функция

```
int accum(int * arr, int N, int init, std::function<int(int,int)> f)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        init = f(init,arr[i]);
    return init;
}
```

Она просто применяет некую функциональность к значениям массива (как у вас). Если это `i+j` - будет суммирование элементов. Если `i*j` - их произведение. Вот тут вместо `f` можно передавать ту же лямбду или функцию. Например, функция

```
int prod(int i, int j)
{
    return i*j;
}
```

умножает числа - и вот произведение всех элементов:

```
cout << "Mul = " << accum(a,6,1,prod) << endl;
```

Или

```
struct square
{
    int operator() (int i, int j) { return i + j*j; }
};
```

для суммирования квадратов:

```
cout << "Sq  = " << accum(a,6,0,square()) << endl;
```

А вот и лямбда - для суммирования элементов:

```
cout << "Sum = " << accum(a,6,0,[](int i, int j) { return i+j; }) << endl;
```

Полный пример - [тут](https://ideone.com/WS4Fx5).

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае можно использовать указатель на функцию. Пример:

```
void getSumMas(var** M, int N, bool (*condition)(int, int))

{
    // здесь можно вызывать condition как обычную функцию
    if (condition(......)) { /* что-то делаете */ }
}
```

Вызов:

```
bool compare(int i, int j)

{
   return i == j  // или что угодно другое
}

getSumMas(M, N, compare)  // Имя функции является указателем на нее
```